# Updating item positions in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: This is how it looks when you select an option from the list]

[image: The next picture is how it looks when you don't choose an item.]

So I am trying to have the results being pulled to the top of the main container instead of showing up like the first picture. Is their a way to do this using jQuery? Kind of like a refresh thing when you choose an item from the list. Or even a way to do this with css maybe, I don't think its possible though. Thanks in advance.

You can view it at http://nathanielmignotte.ca/Work/GridGallery/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you'd like some JS to be executed when a checkbox changes you can use this piece of jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
.on('change', function(e){
    //do stuff
    //if you'd like to know whether the checkbox is checked
    var thisCheckboxIsChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
});
```

To move the `div#grid-gallery` you should first set it's CSS `position` to `relative`. Then you'll first need your initial height of `div#grid-gallery` and store it for easy access:

```
var gallery = $('#grid-gallery'),
    initGalleryHeight = gallery.height();
```

Now create a function which can be called

```
var changeGalleryHeight = function(){
    var curGalleryHeight = gallery.height(),
        diff = curGalleryHeight - initGalleryHeight;

    //set the new top-offset
    gallery.css('top', diff + 'px');
};
```

If you'd call that function on a checkbox `change` you'll be all set.

**EDIT**

First: set `position` of `div#grid-gallery` to `relative`. Otherwise the thing won't go anywhere.

This is your code from `line 97` in `main.js`:

```
var gallery = $('#grid-gallery'),
    initGalleryHeight = gallery.height();

function changePos(){

    var changeGalleryHeight = function(){

        var curGalleryHeight = gallery.height(),
            diff = curGalleryHeight - initGalleryHeight;

        //set the new top-offset
        gallery.css('top', diff + '500px');

    };
}
```

Change it into:

```
var gallery = $('#grid-gallery'),
    initGalleryHeight = gallery.height(),

    changeGalleryHeight = function(){

        var curGalleryHeight = gallery.height(),
        diff = curGalleryHeight - initGalleryHeight;

        //set the new top-offset
        gallery.css('top', diff + 'px');
    };
```

Now that's done all that has to be done is call `changeGalleryHeight()` on a checkbox change:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
.on('change', changeGalleryHeight);
```

Comment: hey sorry man, it cannot be  gallery.css('top', diff + '500px');, because it pushes it downwards instead of up? and when I change it to  gallery.css('top', diff - '500px');, it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know where the `500` came from. I've edited my answer.

Comment: So just leave the px blank section blank then?

Comment: @NathanielM. `gallery.css('top', diff + 'px');` should be correct

Comment: no it doesn't even move says the same place as before

Comment: Hmmm... I have no idea why it shouldn't work. Does the function even get triggered? Also, I found I made a mistake. This isn't the right way to calculate the right offset. If you'd get rid of the absolute positioning the logo's will move up automatically.

Comment: yeah the event is being triggered, cause i alert the diff and its coming up as 500, so it works its just not moving anything up. I put alerts at each stage to see the values and I'm seeing them as well, but I will try the to remove the absolute positioning things.

Comment: if you check the website it will show my alerts I added in and you can see the proper values were get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **isotope.js** from [metafizzy](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) website, it has many features like filtering, sorting ... lists of elements, and it keeps your selected elements always on the top as you want.

Comment: isotope is definitely worth checking out!

Comment: im using masonry for this.